# Rate of change of volume when radius in increasing linearly

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to understand the solution of this problem for quite a while, and I get stuck at one specific line.
Here's the question

> The radius of a sphere is increasing at the rate of  $\frac{1}{\pi}$ m/s, then find change in volume of sphere when radius is 2.5m.

[Original Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1566399/1306295) It's a different question, but the essence remains the same.
In the solution, he differentiates $V$ wrt $t$, in a single line. I would be grateful if someone explained that specific step in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is using chain rule. The given condition is equivalent as saying $\dfrac{dr}{dt}=\pi^{-1}$, so you can get$$\dfrac{dV}{dt}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3\right)=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\dfrac{d(r^3)}{dt}=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\dfrac{dr^3}{dr}\times\dfrac{dr}{dt}=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}(3r^2)\times\dfrac{1}{\pi}$$

Comment: If this is a high school problem, the method often goes by the title "related rates". The solution provided by @AngaeMT is nearly perfect (incomplete - need to substitute r=2.5)

Answer (score 0):

Building on Angae MT's answer, to find the rate when $r=2.5$ we just need to substitute:

$\frac{dV}{dt}_{r=2.5}=4\times (2.5)^{2}$

$=25 m/s$

**EDIT** if you don't see where the $\frac{dV}{dt}$ comes from, write the chain rule:

$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dr}\times\frac{dr}{dt}$

Since we have $V$ as a function of $r$, the first derivative is easy to find. The second is a rate and it is provided in the question.